# If $T^2 = I$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $V = V^{(-1)}\bigoplus V^{(1)}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ such that $T^2 = I$.  Then $V$ is the direct sum of eigenspaces $V^{(-1)}$ and $V^{(1)}$.  I've got that $V^{(-1)}\bigcap V^{(1)} = \{0\}$ and that $v - T(v)$ is either zero or in $V^{(-1)}$, and that $ker(T) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Use Bezout for x-1 and x+1, which is trivial in this case, to prove that the the sum of these two subspaces is the whole space. This is just a very easy particular case of the primary decomposition theorem, if you want to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: For every $v\in V$, 
$$v=\frac{1}{2}(v+Tv)+\frac{1}{2}(v-Tv).$$

Comment: Thanks.  So $V$ is spanned by the subspace.  Is there an even simpler proof though?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: You are welcome. To me, this proof is simple enough. Nevertheless, if you are familiar with [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) of a linear operator, then there is a general conclusion, which says that given a linear operator $T:V\to V$, $V$ can be decomposed into the direct sum of the eigenspaces of $T$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $T$ has no multiple root. In this case, the minimal polynomial is a factor of $x^2-1$, so it has no multiple root.